# Reading Email via IMAP in PHP

Tags: php, email, imap

I need a recommendation for a PHP library that is capable of reading email via the IMAP protocol. I cannot use the standard [PHP: IMAP](http://us.php.net/imap) library because that requires recompiling PHP for the target web server and I don't have access root access to the web server.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603637/processing-imap-email-in-php

Comment: Try https://github.com/MonstaApps/PHP-IMAP-Fetcher. Pipe or fetch emails, log to MySQL, and save attachments.

Answer (score 1):

There is a PEAR package that implements the IMAP protocol: [Net_IMAP](http://pear.php.net/package/Net_IMAP)

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would download [Squirrelmail](http://squirrelmail.org) and look at its source code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any implementation of IMAP for PHP without using PHPs functions.
Maybe you want to use Perl for this: http://search.cpan.org/~conteb/IMAP-Client-0.13/lib/IMAP/Client.pm

Or use a CLI Client when you're on a linux server: http://delog.wordpress.com/2011/05/10/access-imap-server-from-the-command-line-using-openssl/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Context.IO PHP Library: https://github.com/contextio/PHP-ContextIO

Context.IO makes your IMAP store available via a REST interface.  Really easy to use and the price is right.

Comment: On SO, when providing a link to an external site, it is often best to give at least a high level summary of what the contents are in case the external link changes or is deleted. Future SO visitors will still have *something* to work with.